# Spring STS DB connection with Jpa

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am studying Spring STS and trying to connect DB with JPA.

I am unfamiliar with Spring so I have problem in connecting DB.

**if i add pom.xml this code**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**i get this error**

[image]

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE logs.

Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Since you are in a learning phase and using spring-boot depencies, why don't you create a project using "Spring Starter Project" and start from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add spring-beans to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: wow. thank you. 
but error changed if i adding spring-beans and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.
i get 404 error .
The requested resource is not available.
how i solve this problem??

Comment: Can you post the new stacktrace ?

Comment: That's weird, are you sure your application is still deployed ? Or that there is no other error showing up in the logs ?